# Custom function for sum of geometric series of numbers and currencies in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I want my function to be able to handle cell values that are passed as regular numbers, percentages or currencies. Currently only plain numbers work, but when I try it with a currency it generates an error:

```
/**
 * Returns the sum of a geometric serie
 *
 * @param {number} a0 The first element of the serie
 * @param {number} q The ratio
 * @param {number} n Number of elements to sum
 * @return The sum of first n elements.
 * @customfunction
 */
function SUMGEOMSERIE(a0, q, n) {

  if (typeof a0 != 'number') {//|| (typeof q != 'number') || (typeof n != 'number') {
      return null;
   }

  if (q==1)
    return a0*n;
  else
    return a0*(1-Math.pow(q, n))/(1-q);
}
```

### Update

An error occurs when the cells I pass to the function as input are the result of a "complicated" calculation (3-step "backtracking").

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values become decimal numbers in AppScript (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#data_types)), so that should be fine. If you want that as a whole number just multiply by 100. For currency, you can use [`setNumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) on the ranges you are retrieving. You pass in whatever format you would like the number to be in (eg: "0,000.00").

Comment: this solution requires me to create an instance `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` yet I want the script and the spreadsheet to be independent as much as possible. I want to be able to write in a cell `=SUMGEOMSERIE(A1,A2,A3)` and get a result, regardless of the format of the cell. so the format conversion has to happen in the function, without "touching" the cells.

Comment: Hm, not sure I completely understand, but would using `getNumberFormat` and then structuring the output of `SUMGEOMSERIE` to match it work? You'll still have to touch your spreadsheet, but you won't be making any changes.

Comment: I think the issue is not formatting. See the update in my question.

Comment: I think I found the problem. If I pass the function cells that contain numbers or sum of cells with numbers, it works. But if the cell I'm passing is a result of a "complicated" calculation, it doesn't work.